# Simple Oracle Stored Procedure getting Invalid object error

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to write a simple Oracle Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE act.skeleton
IS
DECLARE
  v_rowCount NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(1) INTO v_rowCount FROM ex.emp;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_rowCount);
END;
```

However, when I try & run the procedure by issuing `execute act.skeleton` in PL/SQL Developer command window, I get the following error message:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 11:
PLS-00905: object ACT.SKELETON is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I tried to just run the code without the create procedure statement & it runs successfully with the output being displayed. I have tried both `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE IS` & `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AS` options but I still get the same error.

I am not sure if this has anything to do with authorization or visibility of the procedure when I try and execute it or what is causing the `act.skeleton` object to be invalid. I looked into what the error means & it seems it usually refers to compilation error in the procedure but since I can run the code sans the procedure declaration, I am guessing the declaration piece is the culprit. I just don't know enough to figure out what is causing this and I was hoping that someone will be able to shed some more light on it and point me in the right direction

Thanks,

Ashish

Other Details:

```
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `DECLARE` keyword in a stored procedure declaration. Remove that and it should compile.

Comment: Like this --> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE act.skeleton IS v_rowCount NUMBER;
BEGIN SELECT COUNT(1) INTO v_rowCount FROM ex.emp; DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_rowCount);END;